# how can I create a function of dynamic link in react

Tags: reactjs

when I am clicking on the link it opens the page by pick the id dynamically from database.

I need to create Function so that I have to not create the link again and again.

```
let linkToReminderName='';
if(selectedReminder.Prospect_ID!=='0'){
    linkToReminderName=`/prospect/details/${selectedReminder.Prospect_ID}/contacts`;
}
else if(selectedReminder.Inquiry_ID!=='0'){
    linkToReminderName=`/inquiry/details/${selectedReminder.Inquiry_ID}/contacts`;

}
else if(selectedReminder.Prof_Contact_ID!=='0'){
    linkToReminderName=`/referral/contact/details/${selectedReminder.Prof_Contact_ID}/overall`;

}
let ComLink='';
if(selectedReminder.Prospect_ID!=='0'){
    ComLink=`/prospect/details/${selectedReminder.Prospect_ID}/communications`;

}
else if(selectedReminder.Inquiry_ID!=='0'){
    ComLink=`/inquiry/details/${selectedReminder.Inquiry_ID}/communications`;

}
else if(selectedReminder.Prof_Contact_ID!=='0'){
    ComLink=`/referral/contact/details/${selectedReminder.Prof_Contact_ID}/communications`;

}
```

Comment: ok create a function. post what you have tried here.

Comment: are you using react-router ?

Comment: I am using react router but I need to create a funtion for dynamic links.. can I create it.. @ Fabien Greard

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you should take a look at the doc :

> https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Since you wish to use a function, you just need to change the `${Id}` property with the return of your function, also switch the `{Child}` component as you desire.

I made you a quick example :

```
  <Router>
    <div>
      <h2>Accounts</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to=`/prospect/details/${id}`>Netflix</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <Route path="/prospect/details/:id" component={Child}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

If you wish to add a subroute to it, i recommend you to make a route handler or  a custom route. ( again look at the doc)

A working example : https://codepen.io/FabienGreard/pen/KZgwKO